# LCD interfacing with msp430

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, msp430, ti-ccstudio, hd44780

I am making a contact less tachometer based on magnets .I am using msp430g2253 micro controller and HD44780 lcd.
I have done certain calculations for calculating rpm in the main code and now i want the values to be printed on the LCD but here i am not able to understand how to do it.

```
rpm = cycles*60/1000000; //This is what i want to print on the lcd i.e the value stored 
                           in variable rpm
```

The code of lcd which i have used takes only *char as input , so i am not able to find out a way to convert the integer to char(I know it sounds lame but ...stilll.....) and print it on lcd.

The code below is a part of the whole lcd code, but this is used to print on lcd.

```
void lcdprint(char *text)
{
char *c;
c = text;
while((c !=0) && (*c!=0))
{
    SendByte(*c , dat);
    c++;
}
}
```

So how should i modify this code to print the integer value on lcd. Do i need to create a function for this purpose or what??

**Some details:**
1.Microcontroller used : MSP430G2253
2.Software for coding: Code composer studio (CCS)
3.LCD: HD44780

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have programming experience for TI uCs. I mostly use PICs. In the programs where I need to output numbers on the LCD screen I print char by char on the LCD.

Let's assume that I need to print out the number 123.
First I make a function which divides the number in individual numbers.
Then I display each number on LCD. You can improve the code by your needs.
Example-

```
unsigned char hundreds=0,tens=0,ones=0; //are public to all functions

void
convert_int_char(int input_integer)
{
ones = input_integer % 10; // will give value of 3
tens = ((input_integer % 100) - ones)/10; // will give value of 2
hundreds = (input_integer - ((tens*10)+ones)) / 100; // will give out value of 1 
}

void
lcd_display_char(unsigned char number)
{
 SendByte(number+48 , dat); // Part of your function, to make things more clear.
}
//+48 stands to make the number ascii number. Please see ASCII table.
```

Comment: i had the same code in my mind, but here i need to print an unknown value, which can be of any power either in tens or hundreds or thousand etc,so using the above code does not solve this problem,am i right?

Comment: Just add more thousands, ten_thousand, hundred_thousands.

Comment: ok...i think i can give it a try.Thanks for your inputs

Answer (score 2):

With any luck, your compiler already has the `itoa()` or `sprintf()` function.

If not, you have to implement it yourself.
The important thing is that this must be done from the right to the left:

```c
const char *number_to_string(unsigned int number)
{
    #define BUFFER_SIZE 12
    static char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];  /* must be static to be able to return it */
    char *p;

    p = &buffer[BUFFER_SIZE - 1];
    *p-- = '\0';  /* end of string */
    do {
        unsigned int digit = number % 10;
        *p-- = '0' + digit;
        number = number / 10;
    } while (number > 0);
    return p;  /* first digit might not be at the start of the buffer */
}
```

If you divide by less than 1000000, you can output fractional digits by inserting the decimal point at the appropiate place.

Comment: the compiler do have itoa() function, but when i use that it gives me some sort of error...i will check that and get back to u again.